# getFingerprintGestureController is returning null

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api

I'm trying to create an accessibility service that listens for fingerprint gesture swipes, however when I try to detect if gesture detection is available (using the `isGestureDectionAvailable` method), my app crashes and gives me a null object error, claiming that `getFingerprintGestureController()` is returning null.

Here is the snippet of code in my service's `onCreate` method that seems to be causing the error (Kotlin code, so *fingerprintGestureController* is the `getFingerprintGestureController()` call):

```
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    gestureController = fingerprintGestureController
    gestureDetectionAvailable = gestureController.isGestureDetectionAvailable
    if (!gestureDetectionAvailable) {
        return
    }
    …
}
```

And the error that follows:

*java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.accessibilityservice.IAccessibilityServiceConnection.isFingerprintGestureDetectionAvailable()' on a null object reference …*

Any idea why `getFingerprintGestureController()` isn't returning the controller object? I'm testing on a Pixel and have granted the app accessibility access in the settings.

Comment: did you added <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" /> in you manifest?

Comment: yeah I added that and added the meta-data manifest xml tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I figured out what I was doing wrong. I can only call `getFingerprintGestureController()` once the service has been *connected*. This means I need to move the problem code to the `onServiceConnected()` method.

Furthermore, `onServiceConnected()` is only called once the accessibility service is given permission by the user enabling it in the settings menu. Once the user enables it there, the service is automatically started.

Comment: But in the example code by Android Developers it is called in `onCreate`: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service#configure